# Настройка SSL-подключения к MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных, ssh, ssl

Использую свой компьютер как сервер БД (Windows). Я смотрел в документацию MySQL и не увидел мануала по настройки SSL подключения. Возможно, что я слепой. Но с помощью OpenSSL сгенирировал ключи, положил их в папку cert на C и указал путь. Перезапустил, залогинился mysql -u root -p mypassword

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ко всему прочему съедает символы. Пробовал также в конфиге перед переменными написать ssl, результат одинаков. Изначально client-key и server-key содержали пароли, результат был такой же, позже сбросил пароли

```
openssl rsa -in server-key.pem -out server-key.pem
openssl rsa -in client-key.pem -out client-key.pem
```

Ничего не поменялось.

UPD: Вычитал, что нужно скомпилировать сервер и программы с OpenSSL, это как? Ничего не нашел в гугле.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/11353/72680

Answer (score 1):

В my.ini (в моем случае стоял OpenServer, поэтому конфиг MySQL хранится по пути %путь до OpenServer%\userdata\config) пути до ключей нужно было указывать с двойным слешом.